# Como saber se aplicativo está aberto

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se tem como checar se a aplicação está aberta, com usuário utilizando-a ou se está em segundo plano e ele está utilizando outro aplicativo.

Dependendo se tiver com ele aberto e usuário utilizando ele vou fazer uma função, se ele não tiver vou executar outro comando.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar este código.

```
private boolean verifyApplicationRunning(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
            if (procInfos.get(i).processName.equals(NOME_DO_PACOTE)) {
                onDestroy();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tirado [dessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background):

Você pode tirar proveito do ciclo de vida das activities e manter uma flag que indica se há uma activity em primeiro plano. Ao final de uma transição de uma activity para outra essa flag ficará com o valor `true`; se a activity for para segundo plano, ela ficará com valor `false`.

Primeiro, crie uma classe responsável por gerenciar a flag que indica se alguma activity do aplicativo está em primeiro plano ou não.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible;
  }  

  public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;
  }

  public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;
  }

  private static boolean activityVisible;
}
```

Nota: Não é obrigatório que essa classe estenda `Application`; basta usar uma classe qualquer com métodos acessíveis globalmente pelas activities. Se você optar por estender `Application`, não esqueça de declarar a classe no *AndroidManifest.xml* assim:

```
<application
    android:name="pacote.do.aplicativo.MyApplication"
    ...>
```

Segundo, adicione métodos `onPause()` e `onResume()` a cada uma das activities do projeto. Você pode optar por criar uma classe-pai que implementa esses callbacks e fazer as demais activities estenderem essa classe-pai.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  MyApplication.activityResumed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  MyApplication.activityPaused();
}
```

Pronto, agora sempre que você quiser saber se existe uma activity em primeiro plano, basta verificar chamando `MyApplication.isActivityVisible()`. O próprio ciclo de vida das activities vai se encarregar de manter esse status atualizado.

Para perfeito funcionamento recomendo fazer essa verificação sempre no thread principal. Se for verificar dentro do método `onReceive()` de um broadcast receiver isso já é garantido, agora se fizer isso dentro de um `IntentService` procure usar um `Handler`.

**Restrições dessa abordagem:**

- Você precisa incluir chamadas nos callbacks de ciclo de vida (`onPause`, `onResume`) de todas as activities do seu aplicativo, ou então em uma activity-pai que é estendida pelas demais. Se tiver activities estendendo `ListActivity` ou `MapActivity`, terá que acrescentar os métodos a elas individualmente.
- Para a verificação ser precisa você deve chamar o método de verificação a partir do thread principal (se for chamado em um thread secundário pode acontecer de pegar um valor `false` temporário justamente no meio de uma transição entre activities, quando a flag transita brevemente entre os valores `true` e `false`).

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar o que você quer, precisamos entender um pouco sobre o ciclo de vida de uma `Activity`.

- `onCreate()` é onde você inicializa sua `Activity`. Aqui você chama o método `setContentView()` com o seu arquivo .xml e através do `findViewById()` você referencia seus widgets.
- `onStart()` é chamado quando a sua `Activity` está visível para o usuário. Esse método pode ser chamado várias vezes, inclusive após o `onCreate()`)
- `onResume()` é chamado quando quando a sua `Activity` irá iniciar a intereção com o usuário.
- `onPause()`, ao contrário do `onResume()` é chamado quando o sistema está prestes a iniciar uma outra `Activity` já criada. Aqui geralmente é usado para salvar/persistir dados, parar animações etc.
- `onStop()`, ao contrário do método `onStart()` é chamado quando sua `Activity` não está mais visível para o usuário, pois outra `Activity` esta sendo resumida e esta cobrindo a sua.

Agora, basta você entender e analisar o que melhor se encaixa em sua necessidade para disparar seu método.

Referências:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar uma classe para verificar se o app está em segundo plano com `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`.

```
class ChecarSegundoPlano extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
    final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
    return isAppOnForeground(context);
  }

  private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (appProcesses == null) {
      return false;
    }
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
      if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

// Execute com isto. Quando foregroud for true, sua aplicação estará em primeiro plano.
boolean foregroud = new ChecarSegundoPlano().execute(context).get();
```

[Lei mais...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)

Comment: Me parece correta a resposta, mas uma duvida, da maneira que você fez ele terá que sempre executar `new ChecarSegundoPlano().execute(context).get()` para chegar, correto? Eu não ando trabalhando muito com Java/Android, mas se eu não me engano tem como estender a classe `AsyncTask` para o `Activity` e isto ficaria rodando em um "Thread automaticamente", assim não precisaria ficar fazendo a checagem `doInBackground` executaria sozinho, ou estou enganado, me corrija se eu estiver enganado. :)